# Example of a hacking attempt that failed because of a bug?

Tags: attacks, cyber-warfare

We hear all the time in popular press (and increasingly, in government publications + scholarly articles) about how "cyberattacks" make us insecure, because we have so many vulnerabilities (mostly from a user perspective, but also on occasion from a coding perspective). I'm curious -- are there cases where hacking attempts (either in the commercial or the security sector) failed because *attacker's* code had bugs? I'm assuming this has probably happened frequently, and I'm surprised I've never seen anything about this.

Comment: Does this count? http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/aug/13/snowden-nsa-syria-internet-outage-civil-war

Comment: I also recall that Stuxnet was only discovered when a bug in it caused a PC to repeatedly reboot.